# Printing array of characters using printf

Tags: c, arrays, char, printf

Is there a way I can print an array of characters using 'printf' in the following way (I know this isn't correct C code, I want to know if there is an alternative that will yield the same result).

```
printf("%s", {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o' });
```

Comment: `printf("%s", "hello");`

Comment: Unfortunately they must be in the character array format ('h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o').

Comment: That's the format it needs to be printed? You need to use a loop in that case

Comment: `printf("%.5s", (char[]){'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o' });`

Comment: @M.M that isn't a c string. If that even compiles it might crash.

Comment: @M.M That worked perfectly, thank you!

Comment: @MM why `"%.5s"` and not `"%s"`. What is the difference ? Any way, you forgot `'\0'`

Comment: @Michi There isn't a difference really, only you need a null termination (\0) if you use %s.

Comment: @Michi `%.5s` means to read and output at most 5 characters. I didn't "forget \0", OP has specified that there is no `\0` .

Comment: @user2907877 [Are you sure about that](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=DcEPPPKT)? in that example the `%s` is used so the `'\0'` is needed too.

Comment: @M.M there is no need of `.5` in your example. [The following](http://ideone.com/QU4KxE) should be enough.

Comment: @Michi yes there is, otherwise `%s` will read off the end of the array because there is no `\0` .

Comment: @M.M I do understand your point, but why should he use `.5` instead of adding the `'\0'` ?

Comment: @Michi because he is asking how to print an array that doesn't have a `\0` on it

Comment: @M.M please show me where did he said something about `'\0`. Or you speak about his comment ?

Comment: @Michi he says he wants to print using the syntax `{'h','e','l','l','o'}`. There's no `'\0'` in that. My interpretation of the question is that he does not want to change the array.  If you read the question differently that's your prerogative, you can post your own answer or request clarification from OP.

Comment: @M.M Now I see your point, don't yell please :D. But to be honest we cannot rely on that. Any way thank you for clarification.

Answer (score 3):

This will work, but the length of the array must either be hard-coded in the format string or as a parameter or else the array must be defined twice (perhaps by one macro) so that its size can be calculated by the compiler:

```
printf("%.5s", (char []) {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o' });
```

Comment: I believe you can also specify the length in the format string as a variable: `printf("%*s", length, array);`

Comment: that doesn't change the fact that it must either be hard-coded or taken from a second instance of the array (by sizeof()) (which is of course still all done at compile time, but unless both instances are provided by macro expansion then errors can creep in)

Comment: Why does it have to be done at compile time? This could be in a function that takes a `char*` and `int`. And why do you need another copy for sizeof? `char arr[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c' }; int len = sizeof(arr);`

Comment: It should be `%.5s`, not `%5s`

Comment: because that's the way the question asks for it to be done

Comment: @GregA.Woods How about `'\0'`?

Comment: If a trailing NUL byte were allowed in the array then this wouldn't be much of a question, would it?

Comment: Well, how would you deal with internal `NUL`-bytes?

Comment: The question doesn't have any NUL bytes in it, so, it's not a problem.

Comment: @Deduplicator the answer would still be correct even with internal nul bytes, if we assume that such a byte indicated to stop output

Comment: @GregA.Woods actually it would... what problems do you foresee?

Comment: Assumptions -- dangerous things they are.

Answer (score -1):

How about a simple while loop?  Assuming the array is null-terminated, of course.  If not - you'll need to adjust to counting the number of characters in the array.

```
char a[] = {'h','e','l','l','o','\0'};
int i = 0;
while (a[i] != "\0")
{
   printf ("%c,", a[i]);
   i++;
}
```

Output:

```
h,e,l,l,o,
```

Note: do **NOT** try this on a `char**`! This is for `char[]` only!

Comment: It makes no sense to compare a character to `NULL`.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths: fixed.

Comment: this line: `while (a[i] != "\0")`  will not work as expected.  Suggest: `while (a[i] != '\0')`  as checking characters, not strings